# It's everywhere (yes, everywhere)

Tags: connect-wall

Here are 16 words which can be divided into 4 groups of 4 each.

```
    PLASMAS  HUM      EPIC     BENZ
    OBSC     MUND     COND     HIST
    GRAVEST  CONS     EXT      CAROT
    ARC      OVERT    PROF     FOLDER
```

Can you group each word into the 4 groups, and find the two-word phrase which connects to all 4 of the groups?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this connect-wall can be resolved as follows:

> **Group 1: -ANE**
>  ARCane, MUNDane, HUMane and PROFane
>
>  **Group 2: -ENE**
>  [CAROTene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carotene), [BENZene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene), OBSCene and [EPICene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicenity)
>
>  **Group 3: -OL**
>  [PLASMASol](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plasmasol#:~:text=Medical%20Definition%20of%20plasmasol,a%20pseudopodium%20or%20amoeboid%20cell), [CONSol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consol_(bond)), EXTol, [FOLDERol](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/folderol)
>
>  **Group 4: -ONE**
>  GRAVESTone, OVERTone, CONDone, [HISTone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histone)

What do these 4 groups have in common? These are:

> [Hydrocarbon suffixes](https://www.thoughtco.com/hydrocarbon-nomenclature-prefixes-608208#:~:text=Hydrocarbon%20Suffixes&text=There%20are%20other%20important%20organic,C%2DNH2%20functional%20group) used in **ORGANIC CHEMISTRY**.
>
>  - Compounds ending in '-ANE' have single C-C bonds between all carbon atoms;
>  - Compounds ending in '-ENE' have at least one -C=C- carbon double bond;
>  - Compounds ending in '-OL' contain a -C-OH functional group (alcohols);
>  - Compounds ending in '-ONE' are 'ketones', with the -C=O functional group.

This ties in with the title, of course, since:

> Organic chemistry lies at the very core of all carbon-based living organisms and life as we know it! Pretty much everything, *everywhere*...

Comment: Gah! You are too quick. Just sniped. +1

Comment: Sorry @hexomino! This came up literally just after I posted my own question so I was onto it from pretty much the very first second this time!

Comment: @Stiv Beside nice answer, nice formatting plus cool hyperlinks.

Comment: @Stiv great job! Had this idea sitting in an organic chemistry class and decided to try it out. The checkmark is yours!

Comment: Ah, so inspired by a true story! Well it worked well - a nice themed puzzle @titaniummorro

Answer (score 2):

Group-1:

> Suffix -ANE viz MUNDANE, PROFANE, ARCANE, HUMANE,

Group-2:

> Suffix -ENE viz. BENZENE, CAROTENE,

Group-3:

> Suffix -ONE viz HISTONE, OVERTONE, CONDONE, GRAVESTONE

Group 4:

> Suffix -OL viz. PLASMASOL, FOLDEROL, EXTOL